# Should I downvote a question and make a comment if the OP selected the wrong answer?

Tags: discussion

I know that "wrong" can be subjective, but sometimes I come across questions that will have an accepted answer with only one or two upvotes, or even downvotes, while the next answer is the one that helped me and it has ten plus.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102797/adding-custom-styles-to-ckeditor) is a good example.

Comment: I don't see the need to downvote the question. You should upvote the answer that helped you the most. The accepted answer is the one that help the OP of the question, you can't really say what was good for him.

Comment: Why downvote a question for a bad answer? No.

Comment: @juergend Well, it isn't just a bad answer, it is an accepted bad answer.

Comment: But that's not the poor question's fault.

Comment: @Marc-Andre True, I know that "wrong" can be subjective, but sometimes there are questions with a much obvious better choice (very high vote differential).

Comment: @mattblang Well that what voting is for! You can always leave indication of to other why do you think the answer is bad, but having a bad accepted answer next to a good answer with high vote isn't such a problem in my opinion. Having the accepted status doesn't protect you from downvotes.

Comment: You selected the wrong Answer, Dave Newton's the correct one. -1

Comment: Votes on questions should be based on the quality and content of the question itself. They're not designed to be used as punishment because you don't agree with the choice of answer the poster decided was helpful to them.

Comment: @brasofilo Lol, well played.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see the need to downvote the question. You should upvote the answer that helped you the most. The accepted answer is the one that help the OP of the question, you can't really say what was good for him.

If the accepted is really wrong in some way, you could downvote and leave a comment saying why this particular answer is wrong.

But keep in mind that the accepted answer is only there to say that it help the owner of the question.

From [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

> The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you downvote a question because of an answer? That seems retaliatory and rude.

Comments regarding the question and/or answer are the reason the commenting system exists.

Comment: Well, it isn't just an answer, it is the accepted answer.  So you would say just leave a comment suggesting the seemingly better answer to be accepted but don't vote on the question with the current accepted answer in mind?

Comment: @mattblang What does the *question* have to do with which answer is accepted? Votes on questions are to indicate question quality.